# Document.getElementById() returns element with name equal to id specified

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom, quirks-mode

I have previously mentioned in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281443/regex-find-elements-with-name-attribute-but-not-id) about the funny behavior for IE6/7 (and some versions of Opera) in that `document.getElementById` can find an element whose `name` attribute is defined but not the `id` attribute, such that

```
function f() {
    document.getElementById("a1").value = ...;
}
...
<input name="a1" ...></input>
```

actually works in these versions.

Searching through the net I found [this bug report](http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2005/09/documentgetElementById_may_return_element_with_a_n.html) by Chris Bloom, in which a user named Milo van der Leij points out the following (as referred by him in [this w3c spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3)):

*In their defense: "The id and name attributes share the same name space."*

What does it mean that the id and name attributes share the same namespace? Why would this condition be sufficient for IE6/7/Opera implement this behavior in their JS engine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term `"same namespace"` means that names and ids are not completely separate.  You can use the same `name` and `id` on one particular object, but you cannot use `name="foo"` on one object and `id="foo"` on another object.  That creates a conflict.

It's just the way those browsers decided to implement things.  There's also a global variable for each element with an id that contains the dom element.  That's just the way they implemented things.  It wasn't standard, it isn't the way things are done in more modern browsers (except for some backward compatibility).

Use `id` values for any DOM elements you want to retrieve.  Use `name` values for server identification in posted forms.

Your code will have no conflicts between names and ids if you don't use an `id` on one object and the same `name` on another object, and there generally isn't an issue with giving a particular element the same `name` and `id`.

Comment: If you *must* have an `id` duplicated as a `name` you can use a wrapper around `document.getElementById` and double check it is getting the right element.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher - but `document.getElementById()` only returns one element so if it isn't returning the correct element, then you can't use it to retrieve the element you want so if one were forced to live with a known conflict, you'd probably have to retrieve elements differently.